# How can I do a 301 redirect from http to https in Wildfly 8.2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, redirect, seo, wildfly

My web.xml has the following security constraint:

```
<security-constraint> 
    <web-resource-collection>     
        <web-resource-name>App</web-resource-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection> 
    <user-data-constraint> 
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> 
    </user-data-constraint> 
</security-constraint>
```

This configuration redirects all http URLs to https via 302 redirects. Is there a way to accomplish the same except via 301 redirects in Wildfly 8.2?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to edit undertow itself....no idea how to do that though.

Comment: You indeed need a custom [`ServletExtension`](https://http2.undertow.io/documentation/servlet/servlet-extensions.html). I only can't tell implementation detail from top of head right now.

Comment: @BalusC, I'll take a look at this approach. I'd appreciate it if you can find the time to provide an example. Until then I'll keep reading.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question in the meantime @k170 ?

Comment: @Thermometer, still no answer unfortunately. If I do find one, I'll be sure to post it.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is using Predicates based handlers in undertow. See the example in the link below:

https://http2.undertow.io/documentation/core/predicates-attributes-handlers.html

The example explains a configurable 302 response based on request path. I think you can tweak it to return 301.

Comment: Does that really work on j_security_check too? I don't think so. Or have you tried it yourself?