# How to integrate 'Bouncy Castle' in JBoss 4

Tags: java, jboss, bouncycastle, java-6, tls1.2

I use Jboss 4.4 (Java 6) and i would like to know how to integrate/enable TLSv1.2 
into it. I tried to add:

> security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

into java.security under java/jre/lib/security/
but still i have `handshake_failure`.

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   handshake_failure     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:476)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
>   at com.paypal.core.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:99)
>       at com.paypal.core.APIService.makeRequest(APIService.java:140)
>       at com.paypal.core.BaseService.call(BaseService.java:149)
>       at urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.setExpressCheckout(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:1415)
>       at urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.setExpressCheckout(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:1445)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Java 6/JDK 6 does not [support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) `TLS 1.2`. If I recall correctly JBoss 4.x was never tested with JDK7.

You should disable SSLv3 due to widely known vulnerability [Poodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE).

You need to upgrade to [JBoss EAP 6.4](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap/download/) if you have a Red Hat subscription or [WildFly 9.0.2](http://wildfly.org/downloads/) for TLS 1.2 support and you should use JDK8. After that you can configure your trust store and keys in the SSL subsystem as explained in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008182/wildfly-9-http-to-https).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer.

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer.
I have a large legacy application running jboss4/java6 so I have to check all easy solutions before migration.
My question is would it be possible to maybe hack SSLContext to support TLSv1.2 and use e.g. BouncyCastle to provide implementations?   
Any ideas/suggestions are welcome!