# How to import SSL into WildFly

Tags: ssl-certificate, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have used the WildFly 8.2.0 for changing from HTTP to HTTPS for an application using the procedure given in the following link:  [Wildfly 9 http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008182/wildfly-9-http-to-https)

After following the above step I am able to log in to the application using HTTPS but it gives the untrusted certificate error.

Can anyone help me in installing the self-signed certificate which would resolve the certificate trust issue?

Answer (score 1):

Self-signed certicate is untrusted by definition.

You should buy a certificate from a CA to get a completely valid certificate. And in a production / public environment you should do it.

To avoid the "untrusted certificate" message in a development / test / internal environment, you could create your own SSL Certificate Authority (many examples on internet), sign your certificate by that, then tell your browser (and all browsers connecting to your site) to trust your own CA.

But if your problem is just to accept the untrusted certificate from the browser it depends by your browser. From Chrome you could follow the link "Advanced" then "Go on yourServer (unsecure)".