# Wildfly https redirect

Tags: security, redirect, https, wildfly

I'm currently trying to redirect my http to https on wildfly 10.

In Standalone.xml I have the following configuration:

```
<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="SSLRealm">
            <server-identities>
            <keystore path="/home/vagrant/key-cert.pem keystore-password="password"/>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>    
</management>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SSLRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

The rest of document is untouched.

What i'm missing?

Kind regards.

Comment: Refer post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008182/wildfly-9-http-to-https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008182/wildfly-9-http-to-https)

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: you are missing the "condition" for redirect, usually that is done by adding transport confidential for /* resource of app in web.xml